# How to set up conventional commits in net core solution?

Tags: git, github, asp.net-core, commit

I use ([conventional commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0-beta.3/) with husky package to make sure commit names are following proper format with my Angular front end apps. How can I set up this in microsoft net core solution, based that I need package.json for this to work?

Comment: Have you resolved?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dotnet tool directly from the command line and added to the project through a NuGet package.

Using versionize:
[Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Versionize/),
[source of Versionize](https://github.com/saintedlama/versionize)

..Or set a trigger for pre-commit or post-commit hook, with your own
In the hidden `.git/hooks`, you can create your own commit-msg to enforce the conventional commit message using a regular expression.

This could be your bash script in the commit message file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if ! head -1 "$1" | grep -qE "^(feat|fix|ci|chore|docs|test|style|refactor)(\(.+?\))?: .{1,}$"; then
    echo "Aborting commit. Your commit message is invalid." >&2
    exit 1
fi
if ! head -1 "$1" | grep -qE "^.{1,50}$"; then
    echo "Aborting commit. Your commit message is too long." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

You can automate the copies of the message commit on the MSBuild project copy task.

```
<Target Name="CopyCustomContent" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
        <_CustomFiles Include="..\automation\commit-msg" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(_CustomFiles)" DestinationFolder="./../.git/hooks" />
</Target>
```

Credits:
https://link.medium.com/UweMKDjZ1cb